# Exibir input dependendo do valor no banco de dados?

Tags: php

Bom galera, eu tenho um formulário de uploads, aonde há 6 `input file`.

Em meu banco, possuo uma tabela chamada **login** aonde há varios logins diferentes, é possível eu somente exibir um `input file` se o usuário estiver logado em um login X?

> Exemplo: Se o usuário estiver logado no login "enfermagem", só exibir o input file da enfermagem...

Pensei em usar `IF` e `ELSE`, mas não sei como nessa situação... Alguem me da uma ajudinha plss
[image: Exemplo]

**Meu arquivo de login (seguranca.php)**

```
<?php  
session_start();
if((!isset ($_SESSION['login']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['senha']) == true))
{
  unset($_SESSION['login']);
  unset($_SESSION['senha']);
  header('location:login.php');
  }

$logado = $_SESSION['login'];
?>
```

**EDIT:** 
Meu formulário:

```
<?php 
$codigo_relatorio = $_GET['codigo_relatorio'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM relatorio WHERE codigo_relatorio = '$codigo_relatorio' ");
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
?>


                                             <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Educação Física - Arquivo:</b></b></label>
                                                     <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadsed/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?></a>

                                                    <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="fileed" multiple="" class="form-control-file" >

                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Enfermagem - Arquivo:</b></label>
                                                     <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadsenf/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_enfermagem'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_enfermagem'];?></a>
                                                    <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="file" multiple="" class="form-control-file">

                                            </div>
                                            <br>


                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Nutrição - Arquivo:</b></label>
                                                     <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadsnut/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_nutricao'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_nutricao'];?></a>
                                                    <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="filenut" multiple="" class="form-control-file" >

                                            </div>

                                        <br>

                                             <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Artesanato - Arquivo:</b></label>
                                                     <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadsart/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_artesanato'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_artesanato'];?></a>
                                                    <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="fileart" multiple="" class="form-control-file">

                                            </div>    
                                           <br>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Terapia Ocupacional - Arquivo:</b></label>
                                                     <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadster/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_terapia_ocupacional'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_terapia_ocupacional'];?></a>
                                                    <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="fileter" multiple="" class="form-control-file" >

                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Serviços sociais - Arquivo:</b></label>
                                                     <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadser/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_servicos_sociais'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_servicos_sociais'];}}?></a>
                                                    <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="fileser" multiple="" class="form-control-file" >

                                            </div>
                                            </div>
```

Comment: Seja bemvinda ao SOpt. Por favor adicione todo código que seja relevante para que alguém analise o problema e a ajude a resolvê-lo. Com somente essa imagem é impossível.

Comment: primeiro vá ao banco de dados e retorne o local do login e faça um if, por exemplo `if ($local = "enfermagem") { <input .....}`

Comment: Coloca o código deste formúlario para ajudar na resposta.

Comment: Coloquei o formulário...

Answer (score 0):

Leticía vamos lá, primeiramente, é só você guardar a informação do usuário logado em uma variável SESSION, por exemplo:

```
$tipo = $_SESSION["tipo"];
```

Depois é só você pegar e variável e colocar no if dos campos, exemplo:

```
if($tipo=="enfermagem"){


}
```